# Saving as PDF, under year and month folder

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, directory

I have found this code which works great but I need to save 1 sheet of workbook as pdf. I keep getting error when changing the file format to `xltypepdf`. Can someone please help.

```
Sub DateFolderSave() 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
' Check for year folder and create if needed If 
Len(Dir("C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date), 
vbDirectory)) = 0 Then 
MkDir "C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) 
End If 
' Check for month folder and create if needed If 
Len(Dir("C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) & "\" & 
MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir 
"C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) & "\" & 
MonthName(Month(Date), False)
 End If 
' Check for date folder and create if needed If 
Len(Dir("C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) & "\" & 
MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy"), 
vbDirectory)) = 0 Then 
MkDir "C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) & "\" & 
MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy") 
End If
 ' Save File 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ "C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists 
LC\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, 
"dd.mm.yy") & ".xlsm", _ FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, 
CreateBackup:=False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
' Popup Message MsgBox "File Saved As:" &   vbNewLine & 
C:\Users\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\" & Year(Date) & _ "\" & 
MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't `SaveAs` on a workbook to get a PDF file, you have to `ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF` on the worksheet(s) to do it

Comment: Tip:  When copying your code into the question just copy/paste directly from VBE into the question.  That way you don't have invalid line breaks that make the code un-runnable.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Posted on mobile first and stuffed it up

Comment: @YowE3K -- I'm curious why sometimes you'll "give away" a darn good almost-answer as a comment rather than an answer?  It's tough not to swoop in and retype what you said and score the points!  (I think I may have already inadvertently sniped some points from you that way...)  I figure you're either prompting the OP's to fill in the blanks and answer their own question, or you're afraid that hitting 20,000 rep makes you "old" or something? :)   It's really hard to contain  myself on this one, between your answer sitting there, and the code that's 54% "path" (but who's counting.)

Comment: @ashleedawg Often it is because I am looking at questions just before going to bed, and I don't want to stay up any later checking the documentation (I've never actually used `ExportAsFixedFormat` myself, so would need to read up on it before I posted an answer) but I can supply a quick comment which might give the OP enough of a clue that they can do it themselves.  But if you ever see any of these sort of comments from me, I would be **very** happy if you fleshed it out into a full answer.  Ping me afterwards and I will upvote your answer (or suggest fixes if I don't completely agree).

Comment: @YowE3K -- haha, at first glance I thought you were the OP complaining about having to read stuff.  I was gonna get upset, lol.  Anyhow I posted a new sub for Adam.  95% of that jumble was for figuring out the filename. But it's ok, I'll save the list of links for the next one.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st thing I did (after figuring out where your code started & ended) was Search & Replace, to use 1 variable and 1 constant (instead of the same folder name repeated 8 times).

My sleuth skills tell me that you are brand-new to VBA: working with constants and variables is kinda lesson number one, as they are kinda the basis of *"all of coding & development"*.

But no worries, everyone has to start somewhere.  I rewrote your subroutine:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSheetToPDF()
'exports ActiveWorksheet to dated PDF

    'Set openPDFwhenDone to TRUE to auto-open the PDF when finished
    Const openPDFwhenDone = True

    'Set constant basePath to the file save path
    Const basePath = "C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\"

    'Declare variable pdfPath which for the complete path & filename
    Dim pdfPath As String

    'get the name of the "year" folder
    pdfPath = basePath & Year(Date)

    'if the "year" folder doesn't exist then create it
    If Dir(pdfPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir pdfPath

    'get the name of the "month" folder
    pdfPath = pdfPath & "\" & Format(Month(Date), "00")

    'if the "month" folder doesn't exist then create it
    If Dir(pdfPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir pdfPath

    'get the complete pdf filename
    pdfPath = pdfPath & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf"

    'export active worksheet as PDF to pdfPath
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, pdfPath,,,,,, openPDFwhenDone

    'make sure the pdf file was created
    If Dir(pdfPath) = "" Then
        'file not found
        MsgBox "Something went wrong. (PDF wasn't created.)"
    Else
        'Success!  Show success message (unless PDF was set to auto-open)
        If Not openPDFwhenDoneThen MsgBox "File Saved As:" & vbLf & pdfPath
    End If

End Sub
```

Until I started picking through, I assumed "all that code" was doing a lot more than figuring out the file name and an export!  Take note of which parts of your code were replaced with variable `pdfPath`.  Size may not matter but efficiency and legibility do!

I added lots of comments to the code above so it's easier to understand, but as an example, the code below is pretty much the same, just further compressed.  Actually creating the PDF file is only one line of code.

```
Sub ExportSheetToPDF_smaller()
    Const basePath = "C:\Users\Christine\Desktop\Learner Lists LC\"
    If Dir(basePath & Year(Date), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Year(Date)
    If Dir(basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mm"), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mm")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Format(Date, "yyyy\\mm\\yyyy-mm-dd.p\df"), , , , , , True
    MsgBox "File Saved As:" & vbLf & Dir(basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mm\\yyyy-mm-dd.p\df"))
End Sub
```

So, in return for the free code, you get homework.  *Seriously*.  Please take some time to go through the links below, comparing those commands to the above code samples, as they cover every command that was used, and are a good place to start.  There are lots of other resources out there too (even YouTube is a hidden vault of tutorials)...

**VBA Homework:**

- [VBA Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html)
- [MSDN: Declaring Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-constants)
- [MSDN: Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables)
- [MSDN: Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)
- [MSDN: MkDir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1d22wfh(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.exportasfixedformat?view=vsto-2017)
- [How to use the FORMAT Function with Dates](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)
- [MSDN: Format Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)
- [Option Explicit statement](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)

Let me know if you have any issue getting your PDF export working.

Good Luck!

Comment: I wish I could upvote once for each "homework assignment"!! :D

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Yeah very new still just taking the early step. Appreciate your guidance. Will check out the links.

Comment: You're welcome.  And please do, it's  not as daunting as it looks, and remember, Google is a coder's best friend!